# Something wrong about sqlite when i get some values by id

Tags: android, sqlite, nullpointerexception

My activity is when user is click the save button .It will save its into table.The first click the save button is ok, but Second click save button is error.

This is my activity code

```
save_i.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TableLayout TL = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);

            int countRow = TL.getChildCount();
            //loop
            for(int i=0;i<countRow;i++){
                TableRow TR = (TableRow) TL.getChildAt(i);
                //keep the values in any position
                EditText edIng = (EditText) TR.getChildAt(0);
                EditText edAmo = (EditText) TR.getChildAt(1);
                EditText edUni = (EditText) TR.getChildAt(2);
                //get editText to String
                String ingredient = edIng.getText().toString();
                String amount = edAmo.getText().toString();
                String unit = edUni.getText().toString();
                System.out.println(ingredient+"_"+amount+"_"+unit);

                //save all data to ingredient
                //1.) use menu to find some ingredient.
                ArrayList<IngredientEntry> ingredients = new ArrayList<IngredientEntry>();
                ingredients = db.getIngredientByID(menuID);
                if(ingredients == null){
                    System.out.println("new ingredient");
                    ingredientID = db.insertIngredient(ingredient, unit, null, menuID, amount);
                    System.out.println(ingredientID);
                }else{
                    System.out.println("have ingredient allready");
                }


            }

        }
    });
```

And this is my db solution

```
public ArrayList<IngredientEntry> getIngredientByID(int menuID){

    String menu_ID = Integer.toString(menuID);
    ArrayList<IngredientEntry> ingredients = new ArrayList<IngredientEntry>();
    ingredients = null;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM " + 
            BooksDBHelper.TABLE_INGREDIENT + " WHERE " +
            BooksDBHelper.KEY_MENU_ID + " = ?", 
            new String[]{menu_ID});
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if(cursor.getCount() != 0){

        do{
            IngredientEntry ingredient = new IngredientEntry();
            ingredient.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BooksDBHelper.KEY_NAME)));
            ingredients.add(ingredient);
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());

    }

    return ingredients;

}
```

first click it's go to loop if.It's correct.
Second click it should go to loop else.But it is error.
And this is my logcat

```
02-02 01:10:36.286: E/AndroidRuntime(14242): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-02 01:10:36.286: E/AndroidRuntime(14242): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-02 01:10:36.286: E/AndroidRuntime(14242):    at mutitablesql.db.BooksDB.getIngredientByID(BooksDB.java:128)
02-02 01:10:36.286: E/AndroidRuntime(14242):    at createbook_sub1.create_menu_write$3.onClick(create_menu_write.java:88)
02-02 01:10:36.286: E/AndroidRuntime(14242):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4232)
02-02 01:10:36.286: E/AndroidRuntime(14242):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17298)
02-02 01:10:36.286: E/AndroidRuntime(14242):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
02-02 01:10:36.286: E/AndroidRuntime(14242):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-02 01:10:36.286: E/AndroidRuntime(14242):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-02 01:10:36.286: E/AndroidRuntime(14242):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
02-02 01:10:36.286: E/AndroidRuntime(14242):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-02 01:10:36.286: E/AndroidRuntime(14242):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-02 01:10:36.286: E/AndroidRuntime(14242):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
02-02 01:10:36.286: E/AndroidRuntime(14242):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
02-02 01:10:36.286: E/AndroidRuntime(14242):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the line : `ingredients = null;`
this is what cause the error when you do `ingredients.add(ingredient);`